# Why is this second mysql_fetch_array not working?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, do-while

When I use this second `mysql_query($select_grouppages)`  **within the while loop, then it starts working**, but it stops working when I use it outside the while loop.
The problem is in

```
$select_grouppages_result=mysql_query($select_grouppages) or die(mysql_error());
```

When I use it **outside the do while loop, then it lose its working**.

Please tell me the problem.

```
<?php
$select_pages = "select * from pages";
$select_pages_result = mysql_query($select_pages) or die(mysql_error());
$select_pages_result_row = mysql_fetch_array($select_pages_result);
$select_grouppages = "select * from page_group where group_id=1";
$select_grouppages_result = mysql_query($select_grouppages) or die(mysql_error());
do {
    echo'
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6 mg-top-10"><label>'.$select_pages_result_row['page_name'].'</label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 mg-top-10"><input type="checkbox" name="'.$select_pages_result_row['page_name'].'"';
    if ($select_grouppages_result_row=mysql_fetch_array($select_grouppages_result)){
        if ($select_pages_result_row['page_id']==$select_grouppages_result_row['page_id']){
            echo 'checked';
        }
    }
    echo'></div>
    </div>
    ';
} while ($select_pages_result_row=mysql_fetch_array($select_pages_result));
?>
```

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: U r missing while loop `if ($select_grouppages_result_row` should be `while ($select_grouppages_result_row`

Comment: @devpro no brother it is according to my needs. I used a `do while loop`

Comment: But `if ($select_grouppages_result_row=mysql_fetch_array($select_grouppages_result)){` will not work

Comment: yes it is not working what should i do? @devpro

Comment: I think u need to use foreach or while here

Comment: @devpro How can I?

Comment: As like while loop

Comment: @devpro what is the reason of its not working

Comment: Bcoz you r using it in condition

Comment: @devpro no this is not the reason